# Embed Small Gatsby App into a Wordpress Page?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

I have an existing Wordpress blog. I coded a Amazon booklist app in gatsby that sources content from contentful. I am hosting the gatsby project on Netlify.

Is it possible to embed that app into a page on Wordpress? I feel like this should be simple but I can't think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it as a subdomain through Netlify on your domain and then they can be separate. I don't know that I would embed the page there as their underlying technology is different.

https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/#assign-a-domain-to-a-site

Then just create a link in your Wordpress site to the subdomain page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently exploring options as well. Currently, I have a Gatsby app hosted on Netlify and used an iframe to embed it on my WordPress page:

```
<iframe src="https://your-netlify-domain.netlify.com"></iframe>
```